# Weaker generalization of the Catalan conjecture.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The generalized Catalan conjecture states that for every natural number n, there are only finitely many pairs of perfect powers with difference n,  i.e $x^a - y^b = n$ has finite solutions. What can be said about a weaker version, namely $x^a - y^b = x-y$.
The only solutions I know are $3^2-2^3 = 3-2$ and $13^3-3^7 = 13 - 3$. Can it be shown that there are finite solutions for $(x,y)$ or if there are only a finite number of $(x,y)$

Comment: Rewrite as $x^a-x=y^b-y$ and you have http://oeis.org/A057896, which is conjectured to be finite and complete.

Comment: What do you mean with "weaker" in this context ? Additionally, what do you mean with the last sentence ? Maybe, that $x^a-y^b=x-y$ has only finite many solutions , if $x^a-y^b=n$ has finitely many solutions for every non-zero integer $n$ ?

Comment: I  was trying to ask if given $(x,y)$ there were finite $(a,b)$ and if there are a finite $(x,y,a,b)$ itself